# Почему VS ругается на синтаксис SQL запроса но все равно его выполняет?

Tags: c#, sql, запрос, visual-studio-2015

Только изучаю студию, решил исследовать возможности встроенного Server Explorer на предмет хватит ли его на простые операции типа добавить таблицу, добавить столбец... Пытаюсь цепляться к PostgreSQL
На `SELECT * FROM history` не ругается и выполняет.

На `SELECT * FROM history limit 10` ругается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и **все равно выполняет**. Причем ругается только первый раз, потом жмешь Execute SQL и все нормально, пока например 10 не поменяешь на 4. Снова ругается один раз и дальше выполняет. На `ALTER TABLE` такая же реакция. Что ему надо?.
PS. указал к чему цепляюсь

Comment: Предположу. что он заточен на SQL Server, а не на MySQL, потому ругается.

Comment: А DBMS-то какая? MS SQL поди? Если да - так он про LIMIT и не знает... у него для этого TOP существует...

Comment: Ой да, не уточнил. Цепляюсь к PostgreSQL. Но разве есть разница к чему цепляться если синтаксис одинаков? И к тому же запрос то все равно выполняется правильно потом. Это фишка такая? просто привыкнуть к этому?)

Comment: Вроде в MS SQL Server нет команды LIMIT, а вот в MySQL такая команда есть

Comment: Судя по документации у PostgreSQL такая команда тоже есть

Comment: дак он ее выполняет же , никаких сомнений нет что понимает. прошу 4 - возвращает 4 . прошу 10 - возвращает 10. Но предварительно ругается

Comment: Я конечно не знаю привереден ли он к синтаксису, попробуйте limit заглавными, или в конце поставить ;

Comment: пробовал и то и другое - без разницы. С двух разных компов пробовал

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке- это сообщения парсера среды, а не сервера. А среда (внезапно!) хочет общаться с SQL-сервером того же производителя. Для которого и сообщает, что траблы. Ну а когда ему скажешь "Наплюй!" - он и наплёвывает... до тех пор пока не придёт время парсить следующий запрос (он же не понимает, что там только константа поменялась, для него это вообще новый запрос...). Ну а когда ему сказали не дёргаться, он шлёт запрос, как он есть, серверу... а тот в запросе ничего странного не видит.

Comment: я если покупаю лампочку с цоколем Е27 то по моему нелогично если патрон Е27 начнет ругаться что лампочка не фирмы OSRAM. И ругается то он не на синтаксис MS SQL, а прям на SQL синтаксис. Ну просто если это такая фишка то буду знать) Я вот боюсь только не помешает ли мне эта хрень в дальнейшем, например при создании какого нибудь датасета она бац - и станет блокирующей

Comment: _И ругается то он не на синтаксис MS SQL, а прям на SQL синтаксис._ - в чем по твоему отличие?

Comment: "того же производителя" - скорее всего все гораздо прозаичнее. Поддержку постгрес и др. сделали позже, а изначально поддерживался только MS SQL. Ну забыли про некоторые детали, не покрытые тестами, подумаешь :-)

Comment: *Я вот боюсь только не помешает ли мне эта хрень в дальнейшем* Ты что хотел-то, забыл? ну так я напомню: *решил исследовать возможности встроенного Server Explorer*. Вот и исследовал. А насчёт дальнейшего - чего бы тебе не покопаться в настройках-то? ну должна быть настройка типа "отправлять запросы как есть и не лезть со своими дурацкими советами".

Comment: у меня вот кнопка Verify SQL syntax вообще на любой запрос ругается, даже на простейший select * from table. Неужели и это нормально

Answer (score 1):

Если используете LIMIT, то для избежания непредсказуемого результата лучше это делать вместе с ORDER BY. Это и в [документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html) указано.

> Thus, using different LIMIT/OFFSET values to select different subsets
>   of a query result will give inconsistent results unless you enforce a
>   predictable result ordering with ORDER BY. This is not a bug; it is an
>   inherent consequence of the fact that SQL does not promise to deliver
>   the results of a query in any particular order unless ORDER BY is used
>   to constrain the order.

Comment: Я изначально и использовал его  с ORDER BY, просто не стал писать об этом ибо это никак не влияло на появление окна с ошибкой синтаксиса.